# smart gwt comboBoxItem deosn't filter based on user input

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

```
ComboBoxItem buildings = new ComboBoxItem("buildings", "Building Names") {
        public Criteria getPickListFilterCriteria() {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAttribute("dependentString", grid.getSelectedRecord().getAttribute("company"));
            criteria.setAttribute("dependentString2", "office");
            return criteria;
        }
    };
    buildings.setOptionDataSource(CommonLookupDS.getLookupDS(LookupTypesClient.LOOKUP_BUILDINGS_BY_TYPE));
    buildings.setValueField("key");
    buildings.setDisplayField("value");
    buildings.setWidth(125);
    buildings.setWrapTitle(true);
    buildings.setAutoFetchData(false);
    buildings.setRequired(true);
```

Once the getPickListFilterCriteria method is overridden this comboBox stops filtering for user input. It shows all the options regardless of the user input. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by appending criteria to datasource 
For an example

```
buildings.setOptionDataSource(CommonLookupDS.getLookupDS(LookupTypesClient.LOOKUP_BUILDINGS_BY_TYPE
                                +"&dependentString="+grid.getSelectedRecord().getAttribute("company")+"&dependentString2="+office));
```

and prevent from overriding getPickListFilterCriteria method

Answer (score 1):

I put all my criteria settings to datasource and it works. So, in method transformRequest I do

```
public Object transformRequest(DSRequest dsRequest){
    dsRequest.setHttpMethod("POST");
    return "<json>";
}
```